# PDO bindValue does not work when value from $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a basic rating function using PHP, SQL, PDO, which adds the value of the rating that a user gives to the field "recipe_rating" and then adds 1 to the field "recipe_ratingcounter".

However, something is not quite right with my code below! The two lines $query1->bindValue(2, $recipename); and $query2->bindValue(1, $recipename); are not working properly as they are not actually binding anything to corresponding placeholders in the SQL statement. The SQL syntax is correct as the whole function works perfectly when the $recipename variables above are replaced with a single string like "tuna pasta" or "spag bol" rather than $_GET['name'].

Var_dump shows $recipename as a string when both:

- $recipename = $_GET['name'];
- $recipename = "tuna pasta";

...and therefore I have no idea what to do next as I have tried everything I can think of!

**This works -**

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$selectedrating = $_POST["rating"];
$recipename = "tuna pasta";

global $con;
$query1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_rating = recipe_rating + :recipe_rating WHERE recipe_name = :recipe_name1");
$query1->bindValue(':recipe_rating', $selectedrating);
$query1->bindValue(':recipe_name1', $recipename);
$query1->execute();

$query2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_ratingcounter = recipe_ratingcounter + 1 WHERE recipe_name = :recipe_name2");
$query2->bindValue(':recipe_name2', $recipename);
$query2->execute();
}
```

**But this doesn't work -**

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$selectedrating = $_POST["rating"];
$recipename = $_GET['name'];

global $con;
$query1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_rating = recipe_rating + :recipe_rating WHERE recipe_name = :recipe_name1");
$query1->bindValue(':recipe_rating', $selectedrating);
$query1->bindValue(':recipe_name1', $recipename);
$query1->execute();

$query2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE emptyfridge SET recipe_ratingcounter = recipe_ratingcounter + 1 WHERE recipe_name = :recipe_name2");
$query2->bindValue(':recipe_name2', $recipename);
$query2->execute();
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem confused on whether you're using GET or POST. Try `$_REQUEST` as it covers both.

Comment: There is only one difference between the two cases ($_GET vs $_POST) - hence it is likely the page is being called with an invalid query string (that does not contain 'name' or the expected value).

Comment: There's no difference between your two code samples, other than the get v.s/ tuna bit. mysql or php couldn't care less about that. they'll just be strings as far as either's concerned.

Comment: If $_POST["Submit"] is set, I doubt $_GET["name"] would be set. It is rare to set up a form to submit via POST and GET at the same time.

Comment: Rare but entirely possible if the forms action includes a value. Which is a massive security risk. Hint: Don't use GET for database writes.

Comment: @iamgory POST is no more secure.. only thing it does it keep the data out of the URL (and URLs are often logged so YMMV for 'sensitive' information, but it does not relate to the security/integrity of the saved data).

Comment: Well, it's slightly more secure in that it can at least be hidden from casual users. Ideally he should be using a SESSION variable IMO in the very least.

Comment: @iamgory That's not 'security'.

Comment: I know, hence why I said he shouldn't be using GET. I didn't say he should use POST either, so not sure why you're hammering at me over it.

Comment: @iamgory If not POST, what *should* be used? (In this case the data is information that *needs* to come from the client in one form or another.) The only place the URL will be seen with SSL (which, for non-broken versions with non-compromised certificates and no hijacking proxies, is relatively secure) is in the client browsers or in the server logs. Of course the server gets all the data anyway.. and there are many ways to compromise a local client. Security is, or security isn't.

Comment: i have no interest in the code being secure as it is only a university project. all i want is for it to work properly. i have tried $_REQUEST and i have also tried a $_POST where the value comes from the HTML form, however these both do not work either.
I do not understand why it does not work because the $_GET function that i've used is retrieving what i want it to (ie. "tuna pasta" as a string)

Comment: You probably only included an `id` attribute in your inputs in the html form and not a `name`

Comment: You guys have obviously never used or seen a REST API where a typical POST (or PUT) is to `/resource/{id}`, putting the ID data directly in the URL

Comment: Also @NickMoth, can you define *"doesn't work"*? Make sure PHP is set to show all errors (`display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file) and set PDO to throw exceptions, eg `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Answer (score -1):

`bindValue` is for raw values. Example:

```
$sql->bindValue(":val1", "tuna pasta");
$sql->bindValue(":val2", 1234);
```

You have to use `bindParam` for values within variables. Example:

```
$var1 = "tuna pasta";
$var2 = 1234;
$sql->bindParam(":val1", $var1);
$sql->bindParam(":val2", $var2);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can use variables in `bindValue`, they just won't be bound by reference.